# GetResponse - HttpURLConnection

Tags: java

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Estou tentando ter um retorno `getResponse`. Eu consigo ver o retorno com o `System.out.println`, mas não consigo ter o mesmo retorno dentro da aplicação.

```
HttpURLConnection conexao = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conexao.setDoOutput(true);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conexao.getInputStream()));

             String inputLine = "";
             while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                 System.out.println(inputLine);
             lblStatus.setText(inputLine);


             String respostaenvio = SomenteNumeros(inputLine);

             double resposta = Double.parseDouble(respostaenvio);

             if(resposta > 100000){
                 System.out.println("Enviado");
             }else{
                 System.out.println("Não Enviado");
             }
             in.close();
             conexao.disconnect();
            }
```

Podem me ajudar a entender o que está errado?

Preciso da informação **respostaenvio** para determinar se um SMS foi ou não enviado.

Na linha `System.out.println(inputLine);` imprime exatamente o código que preciso, mas quando tento imprimir este mesmo código em um `JOptionPane`, por exemplo, não vai.

Comment: Você quer setar o valor no inputLine e depois exibir no label?

Comment: O que é que o método `SomenteNumeros` faz?

Comment: o método SomenteNumeros altera o valor recebido para somente números, uma vez que no retorno, existe outros caracteres.

Comment: Laerte, exatamente isso. setar o valor e exibir num label ou JOption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olhe esse seu `while`:

```
String inputLine = "";
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(inputLine);
lblStatus.setText(inputLine);

String respostaenvio = SomenteNumeros(lastLine);
```

Qual é a condição necessária para sair do `while`? É quando a linha lida, que está no `inputLine` for `null`. Isso significa que após o `while` ser finalizado, o `inputLine` vai ser **sempre** `null`, e esse `null` será colocado no label e passado para o método `SomenteNumeros`.

Acho que o que você queria é isso:

```
String inputLine = "";
String lastLine = "";
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    lastLine = inputLine;
    System.out.println(lastLine);
}
lblStatus.setText(lastLine);

String respostaenvio = SomenteNumeros(lastLine);
```

Ou seja, eu tenho uma nova variável `lastLine` que representa a última linha lida **e válida**, e não apenas simplesmente a última linha lida (que será sempre `null` no final).

Comment: Victor, Obrigado pela resposta.

Eu tentei da forma que informou, mas ainda assim não tive retorno na label status.

Anexei uma imagem na pergunta.

Veja que abaixo da linha teste, tem um número.

É este número que preciso num label ou JOptionPane

Comment: @WagnerFilho Mas no seu screenshot não tem a linha `lblStatus.setText(lastLine);` logo após o final do `while`, diferente do que está aqui na resposta.

Comment: Victor
Mancada minha..

Perfeito amigo, funcionou..

Ow. Obrigado mesmo pela ajuda..

Comment: @VictorMancada

Posso fazer uma ultima pergunta?

Em relação ao código acima.
Como posso colocar uma terceira condição if para retornar caso o IP do usuário esteja bloqueado para utilizar a aplicação.

Até o momento tenho duas condições, onde se a resposta for maior que 10000, enviado, se não, não enviado.

Só que o aplicativo tem outro retorno, no caso ACESSO NEGADO.

Então, como faço para obter esta resposta num JOptionPane.show..?

Comment: Consegui @VictorMancada.

if (lblStatus.getText().contains("ACESSO NEGADO"))  {
                        System.out.println("IP não está liberado, favor contatar o administrador do sistema");
}else{
                    String respostaenvio = SomenteNumeros(lastLine);...

Comment: @WagnerFilho Ao invés de usar `if (lblStatus.getText().contains("ACESSO NEGADO"))` eu usaria `if (lastLine.contains("ACESSO NEGADO"))`. Assim fica mais fácil e a lógica do funcionamento do download fica menos acoplada com a lógica dos elementos da tela.